# Programa para resolver sopa de letras

Tags: c++

resulta que necesito un programa que dado 3 enteros x, m y n, una serie de x nombres y una sopa de letras de m x n, encuentre las palabras horizontalmente de izquierda a derecha, verticalmente de arriba a abajo y en diagonal de arriba izquierda a abajo derecha y las transforme a mayúsculas. El programa me da `segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

Un ejemplo del correcto funcionamiento sería:

```
input:
5 6 7
maria jordi joan pere marta
r e m a r i a 
x y a t r w q
j e r e s q s
o o t d a q d 
a v a f h w x
n i i n d a z 

output: 
r e M A R I A
x y A t r w q
J e R e s q s
O O T d a q d
A v A f h w x
N i i N d a z
```

Adjunto el código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

typedef vector<char> fila;
typedef vector<fila> sopa;

void writeNames(int x, vector<string>& names) {
    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
        cin >> names[i];
    }
}

void writeSopa(int m, int n, sopa& lletres) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            cin >> lletres[i][j];
        }
    }
}

bool exploreSpace(string name, const int& i, const int& j, sopa& lletres, int& direction, int m, int n) {
    for (int f = 1; f < name.size(); ++f) {
        if (i + f < m and name[f] != lletres[i][j + f]) direction = 1;
    }
    if (direction == 0) return true;
    for (int f = 1; f < name.size(); ++f) {
        if (j + f < n and name[f] != lletres[i + f][j]) direction = 2;
    }
    if (direction == 1) return true;
    for (int f = 1; f < name.size(); ++f) {
        if (i + f < m and j + f < n and name[f] != lletres[i+f][j + f]) direction = 5;
    }
    if (direction == 2) return true;

    return false;
}

void convertUpper(sopa& lletres, int i, int j, int sizename, int& direction) {
    if (direction == 0) {
        for (int l = 0; l < sizename; ++l) {
            lletres[i][j+l] = lletres[i][j+l] - 'a' + 'A';
        }
    }
    if (direction == 1) {
        for (int l = 0; l < sizename; ++l) {
            lletres[i + l][j] = lletres[i + l][j] - 'a' + 'A';
        }
    }
    if (direction == 2) {
        for (int l = 0; l < sizename; ++l) {
            lletres[i + l][j + l] = lletres[i + l][j + l] - 'a' + 'A';
        }
    }
}

void first_letter(char c, vector<string>& names, const int& i, const int& j, sopa& lletres, int n, int m) {
    int numnames = names.size();
    for(int e = 0; e < numnames; ++e) {
        if (c == names[e][0]) {
            int direction = 0; //if is 0 horitz, 1 vert, 2 diagonal, 5 the word does not appear
            if(exploreSpace(names[e], i, j, lletres, direction, n, m)) {
                convertUpper(lletres, i, j, names[e].size(), direction);
            }
        }
    }
}

void writeSopa(const sopa& lletres, int m, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            cout << lletres[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int x, m, n;
    while (cin >> x >> m >> n) {
        vector<string> names(x);
        writeNames(x, names);
        sopa lletres(m, fila(n));
        writeSopa(m, n, lletres);
        for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
                first_letter(lletres[i][j], names, i, j, lletres, n, m);
            }
        }
        writeSopa(lletres, m, n);
    }

}
```

Comment: Aunque no se si te ayude, Para convertir a mayúscula: char for_uppercase(char c){
    return (c>'Z')?(c-('a'-'A')):c;
}

Comment: @Daniel también puedes hacerlo desctivando el bit 5. `c & ~(1 << 5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función se declara así:

```
bool exploreSpace(string name, const int& i, const int& j, sopa& lletres, int& direction, int m, int n)
```

Pero se llama así:

```
exploreSpace(names[e], i, j, lletres, direction, n, m)
```

Nota que los parámetros `n` y `m` están intercambiados.

---

Por otro lado, `m` es la cantidad de filas. Así que la iteración debería ser sobre los primeros corchetes. Así:

```
if (i + f < m and name[f] != lletres[i + f][j])
    direction = 1;
```

Lo mismo sucede con el otro if. `n` es la cantidad de columnas. Así que debes iterar el segundo corchete:

```
if (j + f < n and name[f] != lletres[i][j + f])
    direction = 2;
```